# Setting IncognitoModeAvailability policy for Google Chrome on an Android tablet?

Tags: chrome-for-android, shell, file-management, file-permissions

Google Chrome supports an “**[IncognitoModeAvailability](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#IncognitoModeAvailability)**” policy that I want to set on my Android (Jelly Bean) tablet.

I tried to set up the policies as described here: http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start. However, the built-in Android File Manager doesn’t allow me to create the required directories; I assume this is because I don’t have enough permissions.

So, my questions are, in ascending order...

1. Is there a way to get the required permissions for the built-in File Manager?
2. Can I launch an Android command-line shell somehow with the required permissions?
3. Is there any way to set this policy via Chrome itself, perhaps with some special command(s) entered in the address bar (the Omnibox)?
4. Alternatively, is there any way to get Chrome’s “Incognito” mode to respect the Google SafeSearch settings that I have locked?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Android.SE! We hope you'll like the place and decide to stay. I notice it's been more than three months, and you haven't gotten any answers yet. Why? I suspect it's because your question wasn't so well-written. If you want real advice on how to disable incognito mode, see [my question on the subject, and the answer,](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/117394/on-the-latest-version-of-android-how-can-i-disable-google-chromes-incognito-mo) instead.