# What to do when "Stop Supervision" does not stop supervision in Google Family Link

Tags: troubleshooting, parental-control, content-filter, google-play-family, google-family-link

I was using the "Google Family Link" parental-control software to supervise a device.  I wanted to stop supervising the device.  So, in the Family Link parent app, I tapped "stop supervision".

Google sent an email saying that I'd stopped supervision.  But Family Link continued to show a notification on the device saying that it was under supervision, and it still continued to forbid certain actions on the device.

Even rebooting the device didn't help.

What's the solution?

Comment: Hi! I have shortened the title. I have added a tag for the software instead of mentioning it upfront in title (can still be searched equally in search engines and here). And thank you for self-answering here. :-)

Comment: Hi :) No problem.

Comment: I've edited the title and tags more.  If we leave the name of the software in the title — even if it's only at the very end of the title — this will make it more obvious to Google searchers that the question is about Family Link.  So this would be a good thing.  Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the solution was simply to wait for several hours.

Within three hours, the notification disappeared, and it became possible to easily and successfully uninstall Google Family Link from the "child" device.

## Edit

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems to me that, on the latest version of Family Link, it's unnecessary to wait even for a few minutes.  Instead, I think it may be enough to simply open the Family Link app on the "child device".  The app should do some checking and immediately realize that supervision has been stopped.